# Session loogging in /etc/profile

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

The session logging we have in {{/etc/profile}} can interfere with services that launch sub-shells as new users - specifically, it *always* launches an interactive terminal, regardless of the context, which can cause certain key processes (e.g. Jenkins) from being able to perform critical tasks.

We had a Jenkins version upgrade and after hte upgrade, Jenkins seems to not be able to restart.  Here’s what’s happening

```ubuntu@hoatname:~$ sudo service jenkins status

Correct java version found

Jenkins Automation Server is not running

ubuntu@hostname:~$ sudo service jenkins start

Correct java version found

- Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins                                                                                                                             jenkins@hostname:~$

jenkins@hostname:~$

jenkins@hostname:~$ sudo service jenkins status

[sudo] password for jenkins:

jenkins@hostname:~$ exit

exit

```
                                                                                                                                                               [fail]
```

ubuntu@hostname:~$

```

Essentially, it seems that “service jenkins start” is somehow causing a session to be created, which dumps it into a script.  I *suspect* this is due to how `/etc/profile` contains a script-based session logger, and i *suspect* that Jenkins is attempting to execute this script when it su’s into its own jenkins user

What should I do to alleviate this?

Comment: This is my /etc/profile

Comment: if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
  if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bash.bashrc
   fi
  else
   if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
    PS1='# '
   else
     PS1='$ '
   fi
  fi
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
 for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
   if [ -r $i ]; then
    . $i
  fi
 done
 unset i
fi
if [ "x$SESSION_RECORD" = "x" ]; then
  timestamp=`date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`
output=/var/log/sessions/$timestamp-$USER.$$
SESSION_RECORD=started
    export SESSION_RECORD
    script -t -f -q 2>${output}.timing $output
exit
fi

Comment: What’s your question? What’s your problem?

Comment: I've updated the question. Please refer